# How to find again the index after pivoting dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I created a dataframe form a csv file containing data on number of deaths by year (running from 1946 to 2021) and month (within year):

```
dataD = pd.read_csv('MY_FILE.csv', sep=',')
```

First rows (out of 902...) of output are :

```
dataD

    Year    Month   Deaths
0   2021    2   55500
1   2021    1   65400
2   2020    12  62800
3   2020    11  64700
4   2020    10  56900
```

As expected, the dataframe contains an **index** numbered `0,1,2,` ... and so on.
Now, I pivot this dataframe in order to have only 1 row by year and months in column, using the following code:

```
dataDW = dataD.pivot(index='Year', columns='Month', values='Deaths')
```

The first rows of the result are now:

```
Month   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
Year                                                
1946    70900.0     53958.0     57287.0     45376.0     42591.0     37721.0     37587.0     34880.0     35188.0     37842.0     42954.0     49596.0
1947    60453.0     56891.0     56442.0     45121.0     42605.0     37894.0     38364.0     36763.0     35768.0     40488.0     41361.0     46007.0
1948    46161.0     45412.0     51983.0     43829.0     42003.0     37084.0     39069.0     35272.0     35314.0     39588.0     43596.0     53899.0
1949    87861.0     58592.0     52772.0     44154.0     41896.0     39141.0     40042.0     37372.0     36267.0     40534.0     47049.0     47918.0
1950    51927.0     47749.0     50439.0     47248.0     45515.0     40095.0     39798.0     38124.0     37075.0     42232.0     44418.0     49860.0
```

**My question is:**
What do I have to change in the previous pivoting code in order to find again the index 0,1,2,..etc. when I output the pivoted file? I think I need to specify `index=***` in order to make the pivot instruction run. But afterwards, I would like to recover an index "*as usual*" (if I can say), exactly like in my first file `dataD`.
Any possibility?

Comment: Looks like it could be, but the new output seems to show "Month" as index; there is not a column apart displaying 0,1,2... Maybe something I don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [**`reset_index()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) after pivoting:

```py
dataDW = dataD.pivot(index='Year', columns='Month', values='Deaths').reset_index()
```

This would give you the following:

```
Month  Year        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       11       12
0      1946  70900.0  53958.0  57287.0  45376.0  42591.0  37721.0  37587.0  34880.0  35188.0  37842.0  42954.0  49596.0
1      1947  60453.0  56891.0  56442.0  45121.0  42605.0  37894.0  38364.0  36763.0  35768.0  40488.0  41361.0  46007.0
2      1948  46161.0  45412.0  51983.0  43829.0  42003.0  37084.0  39069.0  35272.0  35314.0  39588.0  43596.0  53899.0
3      1949  87861.0  58592.0  52772.0  44154.0  41896.0  39141.0  40042.0  37372.0  36267.0  40534.0  47049.0  47918.0
4      1950  51927.0  47749.0  50439.0  47248.0  45515.0  40095.0  39798.0  38124.0  37075.0  42232.0  44418.0  49860.0
```

Note that the "Month" here might look like the index name but is actually `df.columns.name`. You can unset it if preferred:

```py
df.columns.name = None
```

Which then gives you:

```
   Year        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       11       12
0  1946  70900.0  53958.0  57287.0  45376.0  42591.0  37721.0  37587.0  34880.0  35188.0  37842.0  42954.0  49596.0
1  1947  60453.0  56891.0  56442.0  45121.0  42605.0  37894.0  38364.0  36763.0  35768.0  40488.0  41361.0  46007.0
2  1948  46161.0  45412.0  51983.0  43829.0  42003.0  37084.0  39069.0  35272.0  35314.0  39588.0  43596.0  53899.0
3  1949  87861.0  58592.0  52772.0  44154.0  41896.0  39141.0  40042.0  37372.0  36267.0  40534.0  47049.0  47918.0
4  1950  51927.0  47749.0  50439.0  47248.0  45515.0  40095.0  39798.0  38124.0  37075.0  42232.0  44418.0  49860.0
```

Comment: You're welcome! Actually IMO the output is still confusing even after knowing what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: Could you just explain "IMO"? I maybe ask a silly question, but English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Ah sorry, I just meant "in my opinion"

Comment: Good! Improving my Python and English skills at the same time !!!